# Solving an Equation when Every Item is Squared

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have the equation $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$

I want to get it into the form $c = \cdots$

When I take the square root of the whole equation, which items do the $+$ or $-$ go to? Or if my course is completely off, how would this be done?

Comment: On the outside: $c=\pm\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$.

Comment: If it is about the **right angle** triangle then take the **positive value**. Distances are always positive.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can think it in this way:

Either $c$ is positive or negative, its square would be the same. That is the following two cases give the same result for squares:

1. if $c=-1*d$, where $d$ is always a non-negative number. Then
   $$c^2=(-1)^2*d^2=d^2.$$
2. if $c=d$, where $d$ is a non-negative number as before. Then
   $$c^2=d^2.$$

Therefore, the sign of $c$ doesn't make a difference for $c^2$ and hence the equation you have.

To your problem, you should expect $c$ is something like 
$$ \sqrt{a^2+b^2}$$
with a sign in front. Using the conclusion above, you can say either $c$ is non-positive or non-negative, they all satisfy the same equation. Hence, you obtain 
$$c=\pm \sqrt{a^2+b^2}.$$

Hopefully you have a good understanding on the signs now.